Having error while trying to Dual Boot Windows
I tried to install Ubuntu with dual booting with Windows. I selected "Install Ubuntu Alongside Windows Boot Manager" and proceeded with the installation. I reached the step where it says "Copying Files". A minute later I get an error message saying that "Something went wrong". I look at the logs and see an error saying "Stderr: sfdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Operation not supported". I tried formatting the partition in GParted and everything went fine but while installation I am having this error(/dev/sda5 as /boot/efi and /dev/sda6 as /).Full logs are listed in Pastebin(Link-
https://pastebin.com/Kah1GzTw).Running sudo parted -l gives the output- [![sudo parted -l][1]][1]

Connect to the internet, start the installation, update the installer, and continue installing the system.

I tried installing with updated installer and with internet. Yet no luck, it did not work.

Still seems to be a partition issue. In question above post this: sudo parted -l You need to have Windows fast startup, hibernation, & bitlocker all off. NTFS partitions must not need chkdsk and must be "basic" not dynamic".

Still getting the same error, I turned off Fast Startup. I have not turned on Bitlocker nor used hibernation.

Open Windows cmd as administrator, apply this command: powercfg.exe hibernate off, and try again.

Still doesnt work, getting the same error.....
